# How can I enable responses for a Dialogflow Knowledge Base/Document through the V2 API

Tags: dialogflow-es

Looking for information/endpoint on how to enable a knowledge document for answers through the V2 API. The only thing I've found in the docs related to this is here: https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/intents-rich-messages but it only explains how to do things through the UI.

This is the button in the UI:
[Dialogflow enable response button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LoOGn.png)

I've tried watching the network requests when clicking that button but it looks like it's hitting the v1 API which isn't an option as it's about to be deprecated.

If anyone knows this, any help would be greatly appreciated!